# Workday integration task failed

Tags: integration, workday-api

I am trying to run a studio integration that was built in the past - so don't have access to the studio files etc. On running the integration - the following error is encountered.

```
"Integration Failed.  com.capeclear.mediation.MediationException: application=wcc - Workday Out transport id=GetPageOfData encountered problem sending to endpoint 'https://wd3-impl-services1.workday.com/ccx/service/XXXXXXXX/Staffing/v21.0' with operation 'Get_Workers_Request'. Details: MSG_SENSITIVE:XXXXXXX application=wcc - Code: SOAP-ENV:Server.processingError, Reason: Processing error occurred. The task submitted is not authorized. Root Cause: BadRequestException : 
Error code : unknown
Response :<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault xmlns:wd=""urn:com.workday/bsvc"">
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server.processingError</faultcode>
<faultstring>Processing error occurred. The task submitted is not authorized.</faultstring>
<detail>
<wd:Processing_Fault>
<wd:Detail_Message>The task submitted is not authorized.</wd:Detail_Message>
</wd:Processing_Fault>
</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
com.capeclear.cape. See the consolidated report for further details"
```

Initially there was a field override which did not have the required permission - which was added and the Test Field override says that the fields have access. So my question is - does this error mean the "GET_WORKERS_REQUSET" process not have the permissions? Or is it something else at play here?

TIA.

Comment: It could be that the account calling the integration doesn't have permission to call integrations OR that the services called within the integration (source code/missing .clar would help a lot) are outside of the permissions scope for that account. 
--just a few ideas that I hope are helpful. WD Community may be a better spot if you haven't asked there as well.

Comment: Thank you @rihacek

Answer (score 0):

Not Authorized means there is a security issue here. Either you do not have security access to the Business Object (which in this case appears to be "Worker") used for the data or if an ISU/ISSG was created, it hasn't been granted access to the Business Object. I would start there.

Whoever is over your securities would need to grant access to the user/owner of the Integration. After access has been granted try rerunning the Integration.